# Equivalence of convergence in measure and metric for measurable functions

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

Consider the set of equivalence classes of measurable functions on the interval [0,1] and the metric $\rho(f,g) = \int_{0}^{1} \frac{|f(x)-g(x)|}{1+|f(x)-g(x)|} \, d\mu$. It must be proved that $\rho(f_n,f) → 0$ if and only if $f_n$ → f almost everywhere in [0,1].

To prove that convergence by measure implies convergence by metric, it seems to me that it is enough to justify the limiting transition under the sign of the integral. We can do this because $\frac{|f(x)-f_n(x)|}{1+|f(x)-f_n(x)|}$ is majored from above by the number 1 and this will be enough to get convergence by metric.

To prove that convergence by metric follows convergence by measure, I tried to reason from the opposite. Let us have $\rho(f_n,f) → 0$ but at the same time ∃ ε ∃ δ such that |f(x)-$f_n$(x)|≥ε on the interval of measure ≥δ, then $\frac{|f(x)-f_n(x)|}{1+|f(x)-f_n(x)|}$ ≥ $\frac{ε}{1+ε}$ and $\rho(f_n,f) ≥δ*\frac{ε}{1+ε}$ which would contradict convergence by metric.

Can you tell me if the transition to the limit under the integral is justified correctly and to what extent my reasoning is correct?

Comment: For the first part, assume $f_n\to f$ in measure. . You want to use the DCT. Usually the DCT is that $\lim_n \int g_nd\mu=0$ if there is an integrable majorizing function for the sequence and $g_n\to 0$ **almost everywhere**. You do have $1$ as an integrable majorizing function, but we do not know that $\frac{|f_n-f|}{1+|f_n-f|}$ goes to zero almost everywhere. Just that it goes to zero in measure. So you have a good start, but there may be a little more to do there.

Comment: @user469053 DCT also holds with convergence in mesaure. I suspect that OP already knows this.

Comment: I wouldn't want to assume that. I did consider that OP may already know this, which is why I said DCT is "usually" stated this way, and that there "may" be more to do there. OP can confirm.